# Visual Studio causes jerky mouse movements

Tags: windows-10, mouse, visual-studio-2017

When I have a VS instance open, mouse movements are jerky.

When I close it, the issue goes away.

When I have Windows' Task Manager window open *and* active, the mouse moves smoothly, even if VS is also open.

Any ideas?

Some places on the net recommend removing (renaming) the RAVBg64.exe and RAVCpl64.exe files (from Realtek) and rebooting, but that didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I got it fixed.

What I did:

1. Opened NVidia Control Panel
2. In "global settings" I clicked "Restore"
3. In "program settings" I clicked "Restore" for both Visual Studio and Chrome.

That was all.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to hardware acceleration. Have you tried updating your graphics drivers? 
Also, you can try to disable hardware rendering:

> Turn off hardware graphics acceleration to switch to software
>   rendering. To do this, follow these steps: In Visual Studio, click
>   Tools, and then click Options. In the Options dialog box, clear the
>   Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance
>   check box. (Refer to the following screen shot for this step.)

(Taken from the link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues-product-crashes-or-rendering-issues))

Comment: Can you please enter some context about the link you provided? This seems to be a [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) answer. And if the link breaks this answer becomes useless.